# Using DateTime to describe a birthday

Tags: java

I'm using the library DateTime to store date values for birthdays.

```
 DateTime dateTime01Abegin = new DateTime(2013, 5, 23, 00, 00);
 DateTime dateTime01Bbegin = new DateTime(2012, 5, 22, 00, 00);
```

Running the method .getDayOfYear() on them, I am getting a value of 143 for both. But one is May 23rd and one is May 22nd - I can't figure why they're returning the same value!

Comment: Since you don't care about the time, you could also use a [LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html)

Comment: I found the problem! 2012 is a leapyear!!

Comment: @EdwinBuck I assumed that the `DateTime` the OP refers to is from joda time. I wouldn't have mentioned otherwise.

Comment: @assylias I must of missed that, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2012 has 366 (february 29) days and 2013 has 365, that's why both dates return 143.

The count of the days in a year has an offset of one day in leap years, since after february 28 leap years have an additional day compared to normal ones.

Answer (score 5):

Not every year is 365 days long, some years are 366 days long.

2012 is a leap year, which means that it has an additional day, February 29th.  For dates prior to February 28th, the `.getDayOfYear()` will return the same values for similar dates for any year.  For dates after February 28th, `.getDayOfYear()` will return the same values for similar dates if both of those dates are in a leap year, or if both of those dates are not in a leap year.  Otherwise, they should be off by one.

Answer (score 3):

Leapyears. 2012 is a leapyear, so there was a Feb 29th, pushing all the "later" dates up one slot, so your May 22nd is actually day 143 in both years.

Answer (score 1):

2012 was a leap year. So may 23 2013 came 1 day before may 23 2012.